# Сменить цвет текста в input disabled или запретить редактирование с пом. jQuery.

Tags: jquery, css

Всем привет!

Возникла проблема, что цвет текст в инпутах с атрибутом disabled серый. С помощью CSS меняется только в хроме и IE10. Можно ли как то сменить в них цвет?

Есть вариант - запретить редактирование поля с пом. jQuery. Но вот не знаю как..  Варианты, которые я видел предлагают выставить атрибут disabled с помощью jQuery, что ведет обратно к проблеме.

Ну и напоследок осталась идея - перекрыть эти инпуты сверху прозрачным блоком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input:disabled').css('background-color', 'gray');
```

Тут меняется на синий: http://jsfiddle.net/PjCeJ/

Если вы хотите изменить цвет текста, то так:

```
$('input:disabled').css('color', 'gray');
```

Comment: Если вы хотите изменить цвет текста, то так:

    $('input:disabled').css('color', 'gray');

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего запретить изменение другими способами и менять всё, что угодно:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" onselectstart="return false;" onfocus="this.blur();" value="Проверка" style="color:#B00B00;">
```